# MS Word and Shared Hyperlinks

Tags: microsoft-word, hyperlink

I have a big Word document with over a hundred references to about a dozen documents. They want every mention of a document to be linked, but our website is being redesigned, so some of the URLs may change. In InDesign, you can create a "shared hyperlink destination" so that if you need to change it, you only change it once and all links in the text update. Is there a way to do this in Word? My searches so far don't give me much hope, but maybe someone here could help.

Thanks!

Comment: You might be able to do it using bookmark field codes, especially if you can put a bookmark inside a hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to link the text, but you may not be able to hyperlink that text.

In the "shared hyperlink destination" file, the links will need to be marked with bookmarks.

Highlight the text, `Insert -> Bookmark` and give it a sensible name.

```
Insert -> Quick Parts -> Felds -> INCLUDETEXT.
```

Format is `INCLUDETEXT "<path to file>" <bookmark name>`

See [this howtogeek article](https://www.howtogeek.com/240026/how-to-reference-text-from-other-documents-in-microsoft-word/).

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way to do what I want. I instead wrote a macro that searched for a particular string and added/removed/updated the link.